# how to send ViewBag from controller to specific different view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to send the ViewBag from a controller action based in the home controller to a different view rather than the apply View:

```
   public ActionResult Apply(ApplyForAJob applyForAJob)
    {
        applyForAJob.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        applyForAJob.JobId = (int)Session["id"];

    var check = db.ApplyForAJobs.Where(a => a.JobId.Equals(applyForAJob.JobId) && a.UserId.Equals(applyForAJob.UserId)).ToList();
    if(check.Count < 1)
    {
        applyForAJob.ApplyDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.ApplyForAJobs.Add(applyForAJob);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "You have already applied for this job";
    }

    return View();
}
```

The following is details View which exists in the home controller but not within the apply method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Apply","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@ViewBag.Message
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ApplyForAJob</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Something like the following structure will be helpful

```
 return RedirectToAction("Details",ViewBag.Message= "You have already applied for this job");
```

Details Action:

```
   public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Job job = db.Job.Find(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        Session["id"] = id;
        return View(job);
    }
```

Comment: Details is another action method in your same controller ...right?

Comment: yes its another action

Comment: yes but I would like to pass it to different view in the same controller

Comment: @ghassa...changed my answer ,have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

For passing data from one action to another action in the same controller you can use 
Tempdata instead of ViewBag

like

```
public ActionResult Apply()
{
    int id=10;

    TempData["ID"] = id;
    return RedirectToAction("Details");
}

public ActionResult Details()
{

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["ID"]);// id will be 10;
    ViewBag.DemoId= id; 
    return View();  
}
```

and inside your Details View 
use like this

```
<p>Using ViewBag: @ViewBag.DemoId</p>
```

Comment: @ghassa..have you tried with this,try like this it will fix your problem

Comment: I would like to display the message on the same page of the details rather than calling the action apply

Comment: so whats the exact problem overhere ...its fixes your problem if you use it correctly

Comment: I would like to send the ViewBag from an action called apply to a view called details rather than apply view

Comment: @ghassa,edited the answer as per requirement just try with it.and let me know

Comment: calling the method details requires an id

Comment: how can i pass the id in the redirectToAction method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205772/discussion-between-ghassa-and-ishwar-gagare).